# Symfony Rest API lexikjwtauthenticationbundle JWT linux

Tags: symfony

I am using `symfony` Rest API for a web service. I am using the `symfony` `LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle` bundle for authentication and authorization. In Windows it works, but on a Linux I am getting the below error in cache folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uYeQ.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your file name, makes sure it matches your class name.
Linux file system is case sensitive, windows isn't.

Comment: thank you very much i have fixed the issues,,, you are right my JWT class name miss matched in service.yml file. thank you